# How to call the Stored Procedure in the Table Valued Function in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I want to call the Stored Procedure which returns a table in the Table Valued Function. How to create the Table Valued Function?

For Example:  "sp_GetTable" is the Stored procedure. It returns a table.
Here, I want to write one function called "fn_GetTable"

I want to get the same result which has given by Stored Procedure.

Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROC sp_GetTable
AS
BEGIN

------------ Creating TempTable(#MasterTable) ----------------------
    CREATE TABLE #MasterTable
    (ItemID INT, ItemName VARCHAR(100), Specifications VARCHAR(100), D1 VARCHAR(50),   D2 VARCHAR(50), D3 VARCHAR(50), 
        D1_Code VARCHAR(50), D2_Code VARCHAR(50), D3_Code VARCHAR(50))

------------ Creating TempTable(#TempItems) ----------------------

    CREATE TABLE #TempItems(ItemID INT, ItemName VARCHAR(100), Specifications VARCHAR(100), D1 VARCHAR(50), D2 VARCHAR(50), D3 VARCHAR(50),
                 D1_Code VARCHAR(50), D2_Code VARCHAR(50), D3_Code VARCHAR(50))
------------ Creating & Inserting TempTable(@Dim) ----------------------

    DECLARE @Dim TABLE (DCodes VARCHAR(100))
    INSERT INTO @Dim SELECT  D1_Code FROM MAS_SizeType WHERE  D1_Code <> ''
    INSERT INTO @Dim SELECT  D2_Code FROM MAS_SizeType WHERE  D2_Code <> ''
    INSERT INTO @Dim SELECT  D3_Code FROM MAS_SizeType WHERE  D3_Code <> ''

------------ Inserting data into TempTable(#MasterTable) ----------------------

    INSERT INTO #MasterTable
    SELECT     STR_Item.ItemID, STR_Item.ItemName, STR_Item_Specifications.SpecificationName, 
        STR_Item.D1, STR_Item.D2, STR_Item.D3, MAS_SizeType.D1_Code, MAS_SizeType.D2_Code, 
                  MAS_SizeType.D3_Code
    FROM         STR_Item INNER JOIN
                  MAS_SizeType ON STR_Item.SizeTypeID = MAS_SizeType.SizeTypeID INNER JOIN
                  STR_Item_Specifications ON STR_Item.SpecificationID = STR_Item_Specifications.SpecificationID

-------------------- Inserting Data into #TempItems Table ----------------------------
INSERT INTO #TempItems
SELECT 
      *
FROM #MasterTable

------------------Cursor for All dimensions details into single row for each items ----------------------

   DECLARE @DCode VARCHAR(MAX), @Cnt INT
   SET @Cnt = 0

   DECLARE ColAdd CURSOR FOR
   SELECT DISTINCT DCodes FROM @Dim
   OPEN ColAdd
   FETCH NEXT FROM ColAdd INTO @DCode
   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
  SET @Cnt = 1
  EXECUTE ('ALTER TABLE #TempItems ADD ' + @DCode + ' VARCHAR(50)')
  EXECUTE('UPDATE #TempItems SET [' + @DCode + '] = M.D1
                FROM #MasterTable M 
            INNER JOIN #TempItems T ON T.ItemID = M.ItemID AND M.D1_Code = ''' + @DCode + '''')
  EXECUTE('UPDATE #TempItems SET [' + @DCode + '] = M.D2
                FROM #MasterTable M 
            INNER JOIN #TempItems T ON T.ItemID = M.ItemID AND M.D2_Code = ''' + @DCode + '''')
  EXECUTE('UPDATE #TempItems SET [' + @DCode + '] = M.D3
                FROM #MasterTable M 
            INNER JOIN #TempItems T ON T.ItemID = M.ItemID AND M.D3_Code = ''' + @DCode + '''')


    FETCH NEXT FROM ColAdd INTO @DCode
    END
    CLOSE ColAdd
    DEALLOCATE ColAdd
    IF (@Cnt = 1)
    BEGIN

    SELECT  @DCode = STUFF(( SELECT  DISTINCT '],[' + ltrim(DCodes) 
                        FROM  @Dim 
                        ORDER BY '],[' + ltrim(DCodes)
                        FOR XML PATH('')

                                    ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

   EXECUTE ('SELECT ItemID, ItemName, Specifications, ' + @DCode + ' FROM #TempItems ORDER BY ItemName') 
   END

    DROP TABLE #TempItems
    DROP TABLE #MasterTable

END
```

Comment: "I tried like the below, but it gives the error." Why don't you mention the error that was raised?

Comment: @Tim: It gives "Incorrect syntax near 'RETURNS'"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's <strike>possible to do this from within a Scalar Function,</strike> not possible to do from a Table Valued Function. Scalar-valued Functions return a single data-type value and cannot return tables either. Since you cannot select from a stored procedure (you need to `EXEC`) there is no place for this in a table-valued function.

> In general, if the stored procedure
>   returns a, single, result set, define
>   a table-valued function. If the stored
>   procedure computes a scalar value,
>   define a scalar function.

From: [Rewriting Stored Procedures as Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187650.aspx)

Re-writing the Stored Procedure as a Table-Valued Function will yield you the most performance.

Comment: The problem in using the table-valued function is that it should not return the Dynamic columns. It only returns the Static columns. Is there any way to return Dynamic Columns?

Comment: I have to say, the msdn link is b.s, nothing really helpful in it.

Answer (score 3):

Cant be done. You need to rewrite your SP to be a UDF.

**Edit**

Apparently there are some [really ugly workarounds](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost665651.aspx) using `openquery`. But I would recommend rewriting your SP to a function, then you can call the new function from the old SP (if you need to)

Comment: That's still technically a scalar-valued function and can't be used when joining in select statements. I guess the OP wants to use it like a view, perhaps? I'm not sure.

Comment: @Codesleuth: Rewriting to a View or UDF would be the best choice.

Comment: In that stored procedure, I had created two table variables and it contains more statements. Is it possible to create a View?

Comment: @thevan post the SP in your question and I'll help you.

Comment: I posted the SP in my Question. Please give the solution.